# Android devuelve donde se encuentra Object en vez de el contenido

Tags: java, android

Mi problema esque necesito el contenido del Objeto y no lo consigo, al hacerle toString devuelve:

> com.example.sqlexecute.AdaptadorVistaArbol$ViewHolderVistaArbol@81b7ef8

Que si no me equivoco esa es la ruta donde esta "almacenado/creado" el objeto. Como podria conseguir su contenido?

Comment: Personalmente recomendaría agregar un breakpoint ( interrupciones en español)[https://developer.android.com/studio/debug]. Luego de eso cuando tu aplicación llegue hasta ese punto podrás visualizar tu objeto como tal, es decir podrás observar tu objeto, sus métodos, atributos, tipo, etc. De esta manera podrás darte cuenta que objeto es el que necesitas y llamarlo por su nombre.

Comment: Agrega el código de tu objeto, agrega más detalles , revisa [ask].

Comment: Lo siento, ya resolvi el problema, el caso era que estoy utilizando una libreria que descargue de github, pero no venia en la documentacion(que es muy escueta) como manejar el Listener que devolvia el objeto, tenia que hacerle un casting a la clase Miadapter que estoy utilizando(esto lo encontre por google)

Answer (score 1):

Se debe hacer un Override al método `toString()` establecer qué datos se deben retornar cuando sea llamado:

```
class Objeto{
        private String dato1;
        private String dato2;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return dato1 + " " + dato2;
        }
    }
```